# How to check if value coming from Postgres BIGINT is greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, bigint, node-postgres

Javascript does not currently support BIGINT type from Postgres. Many people compensate for this by parsing BIGINT out of databases as a string. This is OK, but I am trying to come up with an implementation where I will parse an integer if it is less than or equal to Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, otherwise return null.

How can I accomplish that?

I am using https://node-postgres.com/

I have one implementation using Number.isSafeInteger(), but I'm not confident it is accurate under all possible values. I don't feel I have enough understanding of 'parseInt()' and 'Number.isSafeInteger()' to know if this will work.

val is passed as type string.

MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is shown below.

```
> Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
9007199254740991
```

The following seems to be accurate.

```
> Number.isSafeInteger(parseInt('9007199254740993'));
false
```

This is the current implementation.

```
types.setTypeParser(20, (val) => {
  const intVal = parseInt(val);
  if (Number.isSafeInteger(intVal)) return intVal;
  return null;
});
```

Comment: Your code should work.